# Have a class act as a dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class defined like so:

```
class GameState:

    def __init__(self, state=None):
        if state is None:
            self.fps = 60
            self.speed = 1
            self.bounciness = 0.9
            self.current_level = None

            self.next_frame_time = 0
            self.init_time = 0
            self.real_time = 0
            self.game_time = 0

            self.game_events = []
            self.real_events = []
        else:
            # THIS being the key line:
            self.__dict__.update(**state)
```

Is there an interface I can define, such that this works (i.e. the ** operator works on my class):

```
>>> a = GameState()
>>> b = GameState(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: update() argument after ** must be a mapping, not GameState
```

Essentially, I want `b` to take on all of the attributes of `a`.

I didn't think it would work, but I tried defining `__getitem__` without any luck.

**EDIT**: I want to avoid using b's `__dict__`, as I want to also be able to pass a dictionary as an argument, and potentially use ** on GameState objects elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order for `**obj` to work, you have to implement (or inherit) the `__getitem__()` and `keys()` methods.

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    return self.__dict__[item] # you maybe should return a copy
def keys(self):
    return self.__dict__.keys() # you could filter those
```

Answer (score 5):

let GameState inherit from dict :

```
class GameState(dict)
```

and rewrite the __setattr function like this :

```
def __setattr__(self,name,value) :
    self.__dict__[name] = value
    self[name] = value
```

Comment: Does this use the `__dict__` for everything, or would I need to define a custom `__getattr__` to look up a name using `self[name]` in order to get my existing `__init__` to work?

Comment: with the __setattr__ addition, it will be both a dict and a normal object

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I'm not sure what other functionality `dict` would provide, so since I'm trying to be as lightweight as possible, I will be using ch3ka's solution, which provides the minimal interface.  Upvote for the useful answer, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

you could do that by updating the b's **dict** with that of a when creating b. Try this out:

```
class GameState:

    def __init__(self, state=None):
        if state is None:
            self.fps = 60
            self.speed = 1
            self.bounciness = 0.9
            self.current_level = None

            self.next_frame_time = 0
            self.init_time = 0
            self.real_time = 0
            self.game_time = 0

            self.game_events = []
            self.real_events = []
        else:
            if type(state) is dict:
                self.__dict__.update(**state)
            else:
                self.__dict__.update(**state.__dict__)

a = GameState() 
b = GameState(a)
```

you might want to create a deepcopy of the dict because you have a list object as part of the attributes. This is safer as there is no sharing of objects.

Comment: I should have put in this in the question (see my edit), but I was hoping to avoid using a's `__dict__`, as I want the ** operator to work on the object.

Comment: you could test for the type of state. If it is an object of type Gamestate then you use `__dict__` else you just use as a normal dict.

Comment: I wouldn't want to have to do this anywhere GameState might be used.  I also think `try: self.__dict__.update(**state); except TypeError: self.__dict__.update(**state.__dict__)` might be more pythonic.  Using `type` is the wrong way to check an object's type.

Comment: +1 for "you might want to create a deepcopy of the dict because you have a list object as part of the attributes. This is safer as there is no sharing of objects." -- Although using `copy.deepcopy` isn't good (I don't want it to go too deep), I have a use-case for keeping the old object.